# Setting up sbt environment to hack on multiple libraries at once

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there an equivalent to Leiningen's "checkouts" feature in sbt?

Here is what I want to accomplish:

I have two projects, an application **Foo** and library "**Bar**".  I want to publish each of these projects independently.  **Foo** depends on **Bar**, and the sbt project will direct sbt to download the jar for "**Bar**" from a repository whenever a third-party tries to build "Foo" (which is typical behavior).

Now, say I want to hack on both **Foo** and **Bar** at the same time.  For example, while working on **Foo**, I want to directly edit and debug some of the source for **Bar** so the edits affect **Foo** (and then later rebuild **Bar** when it is convenient).

How can I instruct sbt to satisfy its dependency on **Bar** from its source code on my machine (rather than my local repository) during this hack session?

(P.S.  I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846706/workflow-for-hacking-on-clojure-libraries-using-swank-clojure) for Clojure/Leiningen.   Leiningen has the ["checkouts"](http://jakemccrary.com/blog/2012/03/28/working-on-multiple-clojure-projects-at-once/) feature which accomplishes this.  I am wondering if there is something similar in sbt...)

Comment: In one terminal (BAR) ```~publish-local```. In another terminal (FOO) ```~reload; compile```. Totally untested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare a source dependency from Foo to Bar via a project reference:

```
import sbt._

object FooBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "foo",
    base = file(".")
  ) dependsOn(theBarBuild)

  lazy val theBarBuild = ProjectRef(
    base = file("/path/to/bar"),
    id = "bar")
}
```

This should also recompile Bar (if it has changed) whenever you compile Foo. Please note that the `id` of the project reference must match the actual id of the Bar project, which might be something like e.g. `default-edd2f8` if you use a simple build definition (`.sbt` files only).

This technique is especially useful for plug-ins (see my [blog post](http://blog.flierl.eu/2012/05/project-references-for-sbt-plug-in.html) about this topic).

**Edit:**

You can kind of re-code the checkout behaviour like this:

```
import sbt._

object FooBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = addCheckouts(Project(id = "foo", base = file(".")))

  def addCheckouts(proj: Project): Project = {
    val checkouts = proj.base.getCanonicalFile / "checkouts"
    if (! checkouts.exists) proj
    else proj.dependsOn(IO.listFiles(DirectoryFilter)(checkouts).map { dir =>
      ProjectRef(base = dir, id = dir.name): ClasspathDep[ProjectReference]
    }:_*)
  }
}
```

This checks your project directory for a `checkouts` directory, and if it exists, adds the directories therein (which should be symlinks to other projects) as project references to the project. It expects the symlink to be named like the actual ID of the linked project (e.g. `default-edd2f8` or `bar`). If the directory doesn't exist, the build just works as before.

When you add or remove a symlink in the checkouts directory (or the directory itself), you must reload the Foo project to pick up the changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also use `RootProject(dir)` to pick the root project without specifying the project ID.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  I tried it and it works.  However, I would ideally like to be able to do this without altering the contents of the projects involved.  Sounds like a job for a plugin?

Comment: Also, per Mark Harrah's advice, I changed `ProjectRef(base = dir, id = dir.name)` to `RootProject(dir)`.  Works great.

Comment: Pretty old post but I give a try : @scrapdog Did you find a way to handle the use case of "if dependency is found locally then use it otherwise go to repo with this default version" without changing the sbt build conf manually? For now we manually changed our build.sbt manually.