# SBT Multi-Project Build with dynamic external projects?

Tags: scala, build, playframework-2.0, sbt

Let's say we have an SBT project `bar` with a dependency on some artifact `foo`:

```
val bar = Project('bar', file('.')).settings(    
  libraryDependencies += "com.foo" % "foo" % "1.0.0"
)
```

However, in certain cases, I want to checkout the source of `foo` and have SBT load the source from my file system instead of the published artifact; that way, I could make local changes to `foo` and immediately test them with `bar` without having to publish anything.

```
val foo = Project('foo', file('foo'))

val bar = Project('bar', file('.')).dependsOn(foo)
```

We have a `spec.json` file in the root folder of `bar` that already specifies if `foo` should be used from source or as an artifact. Is there any way to setup my build to read this file and add `dependsOn` or `libraryDependencies` based on the value in `spec.json`? '

It's easy enough to do this for `libraryDependencies`:

```
val bar = Project('bar', file('.')).settings(    
  libraryDependencies ++= 
    if (containsFoo(baseDirectory.value / "spec.json")) {
      Seq()
    } else {
      Seq("com.foo" % "foo" % "1.0.0")
    }
)
```

However, we can't find any way to set do anything "dynamic" in `dependsOn`, such as reading the `baseDirectory` `SettingKey`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14623138/850196.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried a few approaches, but the only one we could get to work and that didn't feel like an incomprehensible/unmaintainable hack was to add an `implicit class` that adds a method to `Project` that can add a dependency either locally or as an artifact.

Pseudo-code outline of the implementation:

```
implicit class RichProject(val project: Project) extends AnyVal {

  def withSpecDependencies(moduleIds: ModuleID*): Project = {
    // Read the spec.json file that tells us which modules are on the local file system
    val localModuleIds = loadSpec(project.base / "spec.json")

    // Partition the passed in moduleIds into those that are local and those to be downloaded as artifacts
    val (localModules, artifactModules) = moduleIds.partition(localModuleIds.contains)
    val localClasspathDependencies = toClasspathDependencies(localModules)

    project
      .dependsOn(localClasspathDependencies: _*)
      .settings(libraryDependencies ++= artifactDependencies)
  }
}
```

The usage pattern in an actual SBT build is pretty simple:

```
val foo = Project("foo", file("foo")).withSpecDependencies(
  "com.foo" % "bar" % "1.0.0",
  "org.foo" % "bar" % "2.0.0"  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Mecha` build automation SBT plugin does this depending on whether there are other projects on the local file system. It's a new project, so docs are scarce, but you can take a look at its source: https://github.com/storm-enroute/mecha