# SBT Resolve Locally from workspace

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

In SBT/SBT eclipse is there a way to tell eclipse to (temporarily) resolve a dependency from a checked out elipse project rather than from the repository.  Basically functionality similar to that offered by the [workspace resolver in Ivy DE](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/preferences.html)

My use case here is that I want to make some changes to a library project and instantly see the effect they have on one my applications that uses that library.

If such functioanality is not offered- is there another way I could achieve the desired result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623138/how-to-toggle-between-project-and-library-dependencies-in-sbt

Comment: thanks- yes it looks like the accepted answer there (declaring the dependency both as a managed dependency and a project dependency and switching between them based on some env property) is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best or fastest way but you could do:

```
sbt "~publish-local"
```

In the folder of the external lib to publish to your local repository. Everytime a change is made in that code, it will be compiled and resent to the local repository.

Then just

```
 sbt compile
```

In your project

Comment: thanks- until I saw the other answer- this what the solution I was thinking of.