# SBT and Eclipse with Project References?

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, sbt, m2eclipse

I'm considering switching from Maven to SBT.  In part I want to do this so I can cross-deploy my applications to different versions of scala.

I often find it useful to have project references in Eclipse.  However, if I use `sbt sbteclipse` instead of the M2Eclipse plugin, I won't have project references in Eclipse but rather all my dependencies will be from the ivy cache.

Is there an easy way to have project references other than manually deleting the dependency and adding a project reference?  Unfortunately, I would need to do this each time I changed the sbt dependencies since doing so requires me to run `sbt sbteclipse` another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have the sbteclipse plug-in autogenerate project references. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351940/setting-up-sbt-environment-to-hack-on-multiple-libraries-at-once/14352600#14352600) for details.