# How can project/Build.scala use value defined in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I try to use Build.scala build multi-projects.
This is my files directory:

```
MyMainPro/
   app/
       controls/
       models/
       views/
   conf/
       <some files>
   modules/
       anotherProject/
             app/
                 controles/
                 models/
                 views/
             conf/
                 <some files>
             build.sbt
   project/
       <project build files>
       Build.scala
   <other directories>
```

I want invoke the variable inside the build.sbt from my outer Build.scala file. Is that Possible? How to do it.

For instance, my inner build.sbt have a project object:

```
lazy val pil = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.2")
```

How to invoke this project from my outer Build.scala file?
I want to do similar like:

```
lazy val root  = Project(appName, base = file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
.dependsOn(sil)
```

I just want to build my project depend on some OpenSource projects and want to change part of their source code.

I read the http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html
It is only contain how to get varieties from Build.scala to build.sbt.
I want to do the opposite action. That is get varieties from buid.sbt to Build.scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use values from `build.sbt`. But for this case you don't need to; just write

```
lazy val root  = Project(appName, base = file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).
  dependsOn(RootProject(file("modules/anotherProject")))
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352600/9204) for more information on source dependencies).